# Suppress error message when reading user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a Linux script that reads user input like this:

```
read -er user_input
```

This might fail as `-e` is supported in `bash` (perhaps some other shells too), but will fail with e.g. `zsh`. I came up with this:

```
{
    # This may fail. The "e" option is a bash extension that allows user to
    # use arrows to navigate the input. If it fails, we fall back to classic
    # read and ignore the error
    read -er user_input 2> /dev/null
} ||
{
    read -r user_input 
}
```

The idea was that if `read -er user_input` fails, we fall back to what always works. I expected that `2> /dev/null` will eat the error message that stems from lack of support for that option (`Illegal option -e`). What happens though is that user input is not shown either (user does not see what she types).

How to correctly handle this? Or maybe it's safe to assume `e` exists in `bash` only and I should check for what shell we're running? If so, what's the best way to check it?

Comment: As you've noticed, stderr is used for prompts. And yes, personally, I _would_ check the shell. `case $BASH_VERSION in '') do the portable thing;; *) do the bash-only thing;; esac`

Comment: I believe my answer describes that above. (Nothing surprising about stderr -- think about how useless it would be if it were stdout! you couldn't pipe from any program that communicates with the user!)

Comment: (...also, POSIX describes stderr as used for "diagnostic output", and status information -- like "waiting for input", or other logging -- is diagnostic in nature; it's not what the program exists to create, but lets operators know what's going on).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry, I removed my comment as you have added a viable option. Do you think `e` is bash-specific? I didn't want to exclude other shells that support that option.

Comment: `-e`'s interpretation as meaning that readline should be used to allow cursor interaction is _definitely_ bash-specific (readline and bash have the same author, and because readline is GPLed, shells under MIT or BSD licenses don't use it). Could there be another shell that uses it to do a similar prompt with `editline` instead of `readline`? I couldn't write off the possibility.

Comment: That said, in general, scripts should have a shebang that forces them to be executed by the specific shell that they're tested to work with; whereas if something is meant to be sourced rather than executed, it should have a file extension that corresponds with its actual requirements (`.zsh` for zsh-only code, `.bash` for bash-only code, `.sh` for code that makes no assumptions not guaranteed by the POSIX sh standard, etc); that way you can offer a baseline-POSIX version of your shell library, and also bash- or zsh-optimized versions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the detailed explanation, great answer! You could consider adding to it also information why my approach didn't work (the `stderr` used for prompts,  I had no idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to tell if `read -e` is accepted by your current shell (assuming you're willing to take the risk of it meaning something completely different to that shell) is to try it and see:

```
if printf '\n' | read -e >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    read -er user_input
else
    read -r user_input
fi
```

---

As to why redirect stderr suppresses prompting:

POSIX specifies stderr to be used for "diagnostic output", a category that is generally read to include logging, status, and prompting (since the status of a running program -- such as waiting-for-input -- is generally part of understanding its current state and what needs to be done to allow it to successfully complete). Keeping this information away from stdout lets programs communicate with the user even if their output might be directed into a pipeline or away to a file.